# How to write ONE line of command that scp all the sub-directories in a directory to a remote machine

Tags: linux, unix, shell

something like:

```
scp -r all_directories_in_current_directory fenix@xxxxx:~/data
```

anyone can give me a clue?

Comment: Not programming-related - belongs on superuser

Comment: so what errors did you get when you execute the above?

Comment: I think it IS related to shell-programming, right?

Comment: To answer ghostdog74, there are a lot of other files in the directory, so I don't think * alone is enough

Answer (score 9):

```
scp -r * fenix@xxxxx:~/data
```

If you only want the directories, not the files in the current directory:

```
scp -r */ fenix@xxxxx:~/data
```

This will not copy hidded(names startingwith a `.` ) directories.

Answer (score 1):

Use `rsync` rather thsn `scp`, e.g.

```
$ rsync -av ./ fenix@xxxxx:data/
```

Comment: the difference is scp already provides secure connection. If you want to do the same with rsync, it will have to be used with SSH.

Comment: @ghostdog74: Current implementations of rsync already use ssh by default - if you have a very old version of rsync then just add `-e ssh` to the command line.

Answer (score -1):

Do NFS mount, and do `cp -avx`.